# Unable to trust a self signed certificate on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ssl, https

I am currently trying to connect to a server with a self signed certificate.  I am using NSURLConnection to connect to the server.  How can I make sure that I only trust the right server and cancel all other connections?  I am using the following code

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {  

    SecTrustResultType results;
    SecTrustRef trust = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];

    SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &results);

    if (results == kSecTrustResultProceed || results == kSecTrustResultConfirm) {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }

}
```

Currently `SecTrustEvaluate` always returns with results equal to `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure`.  I have installed a configuration profile with the certificate on the phone using the iphone configuration utility and it is marked as verified but it did not change the results.

Can anyone help me get a trust result of either `kSecTrustResultProceed` or `kSecTrustResultConfirm` for a self signed certificate?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to make sure that your certificate has certain extensions.  I configured a certificate with the following extensions, and it worked for me (OpenSSL format):

```
basicConstraints=critical,CA:FALSE
extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth
subjectAltName=IP:192.168.x.y
```

Comment: Nice tip, it works if you are getting **kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure**... specifically the "subjectAltName" key is very important. If your server response by a DNS when it's called you should use `subjectAltName = DNS:example.com` or if you want both `subjectAltName = IP:10.0.1.5,DNS:example.com`.      Thanks !